# Formatação Word e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-word

Colegas, como faria para que uma proposta Word fosse cadastrada dentro do MySQL, podendo ser editada? Tentei usar os editores `wysiwyg` para colocar e colar, porém o HTML do Word, depois de salvo, o MySQL não reconhece.

Resolvido. Havia colocado o código da seguinte forma:

```
addslashes(htmlentities($proposta));
```

Deixei apenas:

```
addslashes()
```

já que o editor `wysiwyg` já cria o HTML. Estou usando o tinymce.

Comment: Explique o "MySQL não reconhece". O que acontece exatamente?

Comment: Tenho um arquivo word e um editor wysiwyg. Quando pego o conteúdo do arquivo word e coloco dentro do editor e clico em salvar, dá erro no cadastro. Já coloquei o addslashes(htmlentities($proposta)); mas não funciona. Dei um print na tela e quando jogo direto no banco de dados, também ocorre o erro. Diz que tem erro de syntax... mas coloquei corretamente o código: insert into tabela values(null,'$proposta'); o que me intriga é que se eu colocar um texto normal, ele grava...

Comment: Consegui... retirei o htmlentities() e funcionou... obrigado!

Comment: @Jose.Marcos seria legal se você respondesse sua própria pergunta (vc pode), incluindo uma solução para a dúvida, mas não apenas "retirei o htmlentities()". Tente expor de uma forma que possa ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Certo Gustavox. Tem razão. Farei isso.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos A forma correta de fazer isso é você responder a sua própria pergunta, utilizando a caixa de resposta, no final da página. Aqui não colocamos a resposta no local destinado a pergunta. A intenção foi boa, mas faz certinho aí, pra ganhar +1. :-)

Comment: Então né, pergunta ainda esta como aberta....

Comment: pronto meu caro SneepS. Resolvido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido. Havia colocado o código da seguinte forma:

addslashes(htmlentities($proposta)); 
Deixei apenas:

addslashes() 
já que o editor wysiwyg já cria o HTML. Estou usando o tinymce.